# float[] behavior

Tags: java

Im sure there is a simple answer to this and I will feel stupid in a few mins but here it goes, it's late and im tired....

So, can i ask, why does this code...

```
public class TestProcess {

    final float[] finalFloats = {0.9f,0.8f,0.7f};
    float[] floats;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestProcess();      
    }

    public TestProcess(){
        floats = finalFloats;
        printTotal();
        floats[0]=0.1f;
        printTotal();
        floats = finalFloats;
        printTotal();
    }

    void printTotal(){
        float count = 0f;
        for(float f : floats){
            count+=f;
        }
        out("Count:"+count);
    }

    void out(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }

}
```

give this output

```
Count:2.4
Count:1.6
Count:1.6
```

When i would expect

```
Count:2.4
Count:1.6
Count:2.4
```

i feel very stupid...!

This question has also been asked [link text](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=5445078&tstart=0), I will post here if it gets answered on the other forum.

Comment: The problem isn't the array, the problem is you misunderstand how references work. (Or don't realise references come into play here)

Comment: +1 - Even though this is a simple question, you've asked it the right way.  You showed your code, showed the output, and told us what you expect the behavior to be.

Comment: Yes i didnt get references are in play here, i was thinking of primitives...doh!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Java arrays are mutable reference types.

When you write `floats = finalFloats;`, you are making the `floats` field refer to the same array instance as `finalFloats`.
Therefore, when you write `floats[0]=0.1f`, you're also modifying the original `finalFloats` array.

All the `final` keyword does is prevent you from assigning `finalFloats` to point to a new instance (eg, `finalFloats = new float[7]`); it doesn't prevent you from mutating the instance.

To make it behave the way you expect, you need to make a copy of the array, like this:

```
floats = Arrays.copyOf(finalFloats, finalFloats.length);
```

Comment: Ah ok, thank you, very clear. I obviosuly have misunderstood the final declaration too, as i thought that ment something could not be modified, more reading for me!  Thank you!!

Comment: I think i made the mistake of thinking a float[] is a primitive...I am tired, thats my only excuse....just realised how easy this question is, oh well